# Configure RPi OpenVPN ip tables problem

Tags: connection, vpn

I am attempting to set up my RPi to work as a VPN server. I used these 2 tutorials: http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-33548728 and https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=81657

When I go to try it (`sudo openvpn /home/(USER)/client1.ovpn`) I enter my password then I get this output on the client:

```
Tue Jan 24 12:06:56 2017 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Tue Jan 24 12:06:57 2017 Control Channel Authentication: tls-auth using INLINE static key file
Tue Jan 24 12:06:57 2017 RESOLVE: Cannot resolve host address: (RPi PUBLIC IP): Address family for hostname not supported
```

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great. (also how do I fix that warning, would I just put `auth-nocache` anywhere in the config file? Some things that come to mind that I might have done wrong: using local ip in place of public ip (both tutorials I looked at didn't really specify which to use 100% of the time, but I did try changing those around to no avail). From the BBC tutorial I am using DES3 or 3 DES (I don't know what this is/means so I just blindly followed the tutorial). I uncommented IPV6 line in sys file to enable packet insertion (the tutorial had me do this for v4 I also tried v6 as I believe that's the type of IP it is.)
What I believe is most likely wrong is the iptables, I've seen multiple ways to do it and I don't know what that all means so again I blindly followed the tutorial.

I tried the BBC way:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.10
# SWAP THE IP NUMBER WITH YOUR RASPBERRY PI IP ADDRESS
```

putting this into a file and having it run at start up. I undid that and tried the other way:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun+ -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
service openvpn restart
```

running this on the server, I receive the same output when I try to start the connection either way.

Server config file (server.config)

```
local (RPi LOCAL IP) # SWAP THIS NUMBER WITH YOUR RASPBERRY PI IP ADDRESS
dev tun
proto udp
port (port #)
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.crt # SWAP XX WITH YOUR SERVER NAME
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.key # SWAP XX WITH YOUR SERVER NAME
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh1024.pem # IF YOU CHANGED YOUR ENCRYPTION TO 20$
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
# server and remote endpoints
ifconfig 10.8.0.1 10.8.0.2
# Add route to Client routing table for the OpenVPN Server
push "route 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.255"
# Add route to Client routing table for the OpenVPN Subnet
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
# your local subnet
push "route 192.168.0.30 255.255.255.0" # SWAP THE IP NUMBER WITH YOUR RASPBERR$
# Set primary domain name server address to the SOHO Router
# If your router does not do DNS, you can use Google DNS 8.8.8.8
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.0.1" # THIS SHOULD ALREADY MATCH YOUR OWN ROUTER $
# Override the Client default gateway by using 0.0.0.0/1 and
# 128.0.0.0/1 rather than 0.0.0.0/0. This has the benefit of
# overriding but not wiping out the original default gateway.
push "redirect-gateway def1"
client-to-client
duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ta.key 0
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log 20
log /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 1
```

Client config (client1.ovpn):

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote (RPi PUBLIC IP) (PORT) #REPLACE YOUR DYNAMIC DNS VA$
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
mute-replay-warnings
ns-cert-type server
key-direction 1
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 1
mute 20
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(RANDOM LETTERS)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(RANDOM LETTERS)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC, (Random letters)
(MORE RANDOM LETTERS)
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<tls-auth>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
(EVEN MORE RANDOM LETTERS)
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
```

Comment: *"would I just put auth-nocache anywhere in the config file"* -> Yes.